# Proper use of structs in yacc

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

Please Help ! I'm a newbie and I'm trying to program a parser using flex-bison and I'm required to use a record type, I have no idea why should I use it that first and second when I tried to use it a confliction in type happendi I guess, and it gave me this list of errors [image]

This is the definition of the type in the file **global.h**

```
struct Point{
int *x;
int *y;
};
typedef struct Point Point;
#define YYSTYPE Point
extern YYSTYPE yylval;
```

Knowing that a figure may have 3 to 4 segments, this is the kind of text to parse

```
 Figure{
 Segment{
 Point(1,30)
 Point(20,30)
 }
 Segment{
 Point(20,30)
 Point(2,10)
 }
 Segment{
 Point(2,10)
 Point(1,30)
 }
 }
```

This is what I tried to do

mes_tokens.l

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "global.h"
#include "y.tab.h"
extern YYSTYPE yylval;
struct Point *tmp;
%}
%option noyywrap
blanks         [ \t\n]+
accolade_close      \}
comma                        \,
number          [0-9]+
%x ABS ORD
%%
{blanks}        { /* ignore */ }
"Point(" {BEGIN(ABS);}
<ABS>{number} { 
tmp= (struct Point*) malloc(sizeof(struct Point));
tmp->x=atoi(yytext); }
<ABS>{comma} {BEGIN(ORD); }
<ORD>{number} { 
tmp->y=atoi(yytext);
//yylval= ( Point *) malloc(sizeof(Point)); 
yylval.x= tmp->x;
yylval.y= tmp->y;
return POINT;
}
<ORD>\) { BEGIN(INITIAL);}
"Figure{" { return(FIGURE); }
"Segment{"   { return(SEGMENT); }
{accolade_close}    { return(ACCOLADE_CLOSE); }
.    { yyerror("Unknown char");  }
%%
```

figure.y

```
   %{
#include "global.h"
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int yyparse();
int yylex();
int yyerror(char *s);
%}
%union {
struct Point *point;
 }
%token <Point> FIGURE SEGMENT POINT ACCOLADE_CLOSE 
%start Input
%%
Input:FIGURE ListSegment ACCOLADE_CLOSE 
 ;
ListSegment: Seg Seg Seg Seg
       | Seg Seg Seg
       ;
 Seg: SEGMENT POINT POINT ACCOLADE_CLOSE { printf("Segment Point1 
 (%d,%d)\n",$2->x, $2->y);}

 %%

int yyerror(char *s) {
printf("yyerror : %s\n ",s);
return 0;
}

int main(void) {
yyparse();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you'vee defined it, `yylval` *is* a `Point`. Not *has* a `point` member. Make up your mind.

The normal thing would be to define the `yyunion` as *having* a `point` member, which agrees with the code in your .y file.

Comment: I'm sorry it's all new to me, I made some modifications now, the error has no member is gone, but the warning are still there , and when I took off the `printf`statement It kind of worked, when I added it back and tried different forms to display it $2->x $2.x $<point.w>$2 It didn't work

Comment: It's no good telling us all that without showing what you did. And *please* don't post it as a comment.

Comment: `$2` is a `yyunion`, not a `yyunion *`, so `$2->x` should be `$2.x`, and similarly.

Comment: As it is in the picture above for the printf line and tmp->x=atoi(yytext); in the lex file

Comment: There are two errors there. You got them both? Be clear.

Comment: Yes both, and when I remove the printf the structure has no member error  disapear (excuse my english)

Comment: There is nothing here that uses `Point` as a data member name. If you are getting a message about no member named `Point`, this is not the real code. You need some `%type` delcarations too. In fact you eed to study the documentation and some examples. Too broad.

Comment: I just double checked and it is the real code, Thank you very much anyway I've learned few things here

Comment: @EJP there is no need to snap.